# INSERT Statement in PL/SQL fails in Oracle database

Tags: oracle, plsql

When executing an SQL statement in PLSQL with

```
DBMS_SQL.EXECUTE('insert into tablename VALUES(aNumber)');
```

It gives an ASCII character error.
And when inserting it directly it succeeds and inserts it.

Comment: Please provide a complete example. As it is `tablevalue` is an invalid identifier and can't be inserted.

Comment: The closing parenthesis is missing.

Comment: Why do you want to use DBMS_SQL? If you really need dynamic SQL, EXECUTE IMMEDIATE seems a much more sensible choice for such a simple task.

Comment: @Toru That was just a typo when I wrote this question.

Answer (score 7):

In PL/SQL you could write the `INSERT` statement directly.

```
DECLARE
  tablevalue      varchar2(200);
BEGIN
  tablevalue := 'Hello World!';

  INSERT   INTO tablename
         VALUES (tablevalue);
END;
```

Your statement fails because that is not the way `DBMS_SQL.EXECUTE` works. Check out the documentation and the example: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_sql.htm#BABBFFFJ

According to the example given in the reference documentation you should do it like this (first you prepare the statement, then bind the variable and then run it).

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE demo(tablevalue IN varchar2) AS
    cursor_name INTEGER;
    rows_processed INTEGER;
BEGIN
    cursor_name := dbms_sql.open_cursor;
    DBMS_SQL.PARSE(cursor_name, 'INSERT INTO tablename VALUES(:x)',
                   DBMS_SQL.NATIVE);
    DBMS_SQL.BIND_VARIABLE(cursor_name, ':x', tablevalue);
    rows_processed := DBMS_SQL.EXECUTE(cursor_name);
    DBMS_SQL.CLOSE_CURSOR(cursor_name);
EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS THEN
    DBMS_SQL.CLOSE_CURSOR(cursor_name);
    raise;
END;
```

You use it then like this

```
 exec demo('something');
```

Hope it helps