# Dynamic SQL, comparing two records one column at a time

Tags: oracle, dynamic, plsql, record, rowtype

Scenario: we have flashback set up on certain tables in a Oracle database. Every now and then, we want to see what fields changed from one row to another.  We can inspect visually of course but that is error-prone.

So I had the "brilliant" idea to try to step through the rows, store the current record into one record variable, and the prior record into another one.  Then, field-by-field, compare each field, and if different, print out the field name and the values.  Something like this:

```
DECLARE CURSOR myflash IS SELECT * FROM myflashtable;
OLDRECORD myflashtable%ROWTYPE;
NEWRECORD myflashtable%ROWTYPE;
dynamic_statement varchar2(4000);
cursor colnames is select * from all_tab_columns where table_name = 'myflashtable';
begin
if not myflash%ISOPEN then
  open myflash;
end if;
fetch myflash into NEWRECORD;
while myflash%FOUND loop;
  for columnnames in colnames loop
      /* cobble together dynamic SQL along the lines of
         "if oldrecord.column_name != newrecord.column_name 
         then print some information``....end if;"
      */
         execute immediate dynamic_statement;
  end loop;
  OLDRECORD := NEWRECORD;
  fetch myflash into NEWRECORD;
end loop;
end;
```

Naturally this didn't work. Initially it gave me "invalid SQL statement" and I added begin/end onto the dynamic SQL. When I tried running *that* version, it gave me an error because it doesn't know about the old/new records.  When I run without doing the execute, but just dumping the generated SQL, it is stepping through all the columns on each of the records, so that part of the logic is working.

I'm quite sure there's a better way to do this, or perhaps to make it work. One thought was to do something like declaring old/new value variables, then using dynamic SQL to move the old/new record fields to each of those:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'oldvalue := OLDRECORD.'||columnnames.column_name;
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'newvalue := NEWRECORD.'||columnnames.column_name;
IF oldvalue != newvalue then
   /* print some stuff */
END IF:
```

but of course the trick is that the target variable would have to handle columns of a bunch of different types - char, date, etc. So there'd need to be variants of old/newvalue variables, and logic to handle that, and it was turning into not-so-much-fun.

Any suggestions for a more elegant way to do this?  I've checked around the site and haven't had much like finding anything that quite seemed like what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track. But it is quite some more programming work to do. Read the old and new table in a join linking it with the correct primary key and loop through it. You can use `DMBS_SQL` package to build a dynamic cursor and loop through the tables.

Comment: They're actually the same table, just different rows for different instances. A new row is written every time the record is saved with any changes. The "key" would be the basic key(s) of the table being tracked - for example if it's a college, it might be their student ID - plus a couple of auditing fields.  So the sort would be something like student_id plus flashback_sequence_number.  We can't do a direct join because we don't know whether that student's next flash record is key + 1, key + 100, or whatever - hence sequentially looping through.

Comment: Ran out of characters, but: So the looping through records is fine. But there are dozens and dozens of columns on that table. I could add them all to the code and do 'if old.field1 != new.field1 then print' ad infinitum, but it's too easy to miss fields that way. So I'd been hoping there was an easy way to use the metadata to construct the SQL with the column names - this would let us use nearly-identical code for other auditing as well (as well as being more resilient if columns change).

Comment: If you can write a `SELECT` with a `WHEN` that gives you the right result then you can do it with dynamic SQL. How about you edit your original question and add a `SELECT` statement as you would fetch two rows you want to compare. I am sure I can help you from there.

Comment: Ah - just reread and saw that you mentioned DBMS_SQL package. I'd heard of that but couldn't figure out how to use it (or whether it would work for this situation). Any hints?

Comment: I have added an example and reference to the documentation in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16837600/insert-statement-in-pl-sql-fails-in-oracle-database/16844662#16844662

Comment: Thanks - this gives me some ideas. Simply adding select to get the two records isn't practical in this situation for the simple reason that the tables aren't indexed. Plus, the unique key field(s) aren't necessarily sequential What I'd be looking for is along the lines of:  "select * from flashtable2 where flashtable2.studentid = flashtable1.studentid and flashtable2.flashid = (select min (flashid) from flashtable3 where flashtable3.studentid = flashtable1.studentid and flashtable3.flashid > flashtable1.flashid)". No indexes = takes forever to run.

Comment: Maybe something along the lines of binding the records to something in DBMS_SQL, similarly binding the fieldname, and having (with the DMBS_SQL execution) some kind of EXECUTE IMMEDIATE?  Is there a way to send that result back to the "main" program via another BIND? A simple boolean would suffice, though the actual values would be good too if possible. Obviously I'm not too "up" on how DBMS_SQL works and the various websites don't shed too much light on it; haven't had a chance to try any of this out which I'm sure would help :-)